# Правильная обработка POST

Tags: post, html

Есть таблица в несколько строчек. Нажимаю редактировать - открывается форма. Редактирую... Нажимаю Submit - перехожу на таблицу. Всё работает...

НО при обновлении страницы (там, где таблица) выскакивает окошко: "На странице, которую вы ищете, использовалась введенная вами информация. При возврате на эту страницу может потребоваться повторить выполненные ранее действия. Продолжить?"

Что нужно сделать, чтобы не появлялось это окошко?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%D0%9D%D0%B0+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%2C+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E+%D0%B2%D1%8B+%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%2C+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: У меня тоже самое при входе на сайт пенсионного фонда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка "Сохранить" -> POST-запрос, чтобы сохранить -> после сохранения ничего не показываем, а редирект на следующую страницу, где просто отображается таблица.

Такой паттерн называется PRG ([POST-Redirect-GET](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).

Comment: Спасибо. Так и думал... Хотя надеялся, что есть какой-нибудь более хитрый способ))) А тут, оказывается, на это дело есть даже целый паттерн!

Comment: @sitev_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).